# empty() considers a value as empty

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to follow a reference to answer but not sure on how it should be written:

> The empty() considers a '0' as empty so in $p_student =
>   empty($_POST["student"])?'':$_POST["student"]; $p_student is true when
>   $_POST["student"] is '0'... As a result, the case below is always
>   'default', so you should may be set $p_student as a '0' if empty() and
>   it should be ok...I think... ( Thats for both $p_student and
>   $p_question of course...)

I have set up a case statement to match above example but my question is how should $p_student should be written depending on above's example?

My attempt:

```
// Check whether a specific student was selected
    $p_student = empty($_POST["student"])?'0':$_POST["student"];

    switch($p_student){
    case -1:
        //dont' add where filters
        break;
    default:
        $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
        $parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];
        $parameterTypes .= 'i';
    }
```

UPDATE:

What I was trying to do is that if `All` option, then perform case -1, else perform default. Am I doing anything wrong because this is why I am asking this question on the drop down values:

**Student:**

```
<select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<option value="-1">All</option>
<option value="39">Luke Mcfadzen</option>
<option value="40">Chris Tucker</option>
</select>
```

**Question:**

```
<select name="question" id="questionsDrop">
<option value="-1">All</option>
<option value="72">1</option>
<option value="73">2</option>
</select>
```

**Dynamic where clause is what I am attempting depending if user selects all students or an individual student and All Questions or individual questions.. If individual then look up student using where clause and same for question, if all students then no need for where condition for student as we are not looking for specific student, this works same way for questions. The query has a compulsory WHERE condition check for `q.SessionId = ?`**

I am receiving errors stating:

```
$selectedstudentanswerqry = "
    SELECT
    sa.StudentId, StudentAlias, StudentForename, ...
    FROM Student st
    ...
    ";

    // Initially empty
    $where[] = "q.SessionId = ?";
    $parameters[] = $_POST["session"];
    $parameterTypes = 'i';


    //check if POST is empty

    // Check whether a specific student was selected
//LINE 345 ERROR
$student_id = (isset($_POST['student'])) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['student'])) : null ;


if (is_numeric($student_id)){ //If student ID is a numeric value
  $where[] = "sa.StudentId = ?" ;
  $parameters[] = ((int)$student_id == -1) ? "sa.StudentId" : $student_id  ;
  $parameterTypes .= "i" ;
}

    // Check whether a specific question was selected

$question_id = (isset($_POST['question'])) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['question'])) : null ;

if (is_numeric($question_id)){ //If student ID is a numeric value
  $where[] = "q.QuestionId = ?" ;
  $parameters[] = ((int)$question_id == -1) ? "q.QuestionId" : $question_id  ;
  $parameterTypes .= "i" ;
}

    // If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
    // our query
    if(!empty($where)) {
        $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
        global $mysqli;
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry);
        // You only need to call bind_param once

        if (count($where) == 1) {
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0]);
    }
    else if (count($where) == 2) {
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1]);
    }
    else if (count($where) == 3) {
        $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes, $parameters[0], $parameters[1], $parameters[2]);
    }

    }

    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
      GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
      ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
    ";

// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result(...);   

$selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
$selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows();
```

Comment: [PHP manual on empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) explains the values that are considered empty. So, like the answers below, if the `$_POST` value could be any of them, try something other than `empty()`. Example: http://codepad.org/XTqeplDE

Comment: `$parameters[] .= $_POST["student"];` ?? Change that `.=` to `=`. You are not doing string concatenation onto the array.

Comment: @user2048994 It's ok to clarify with an update.  You don't need to call `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the value because you are binding it in `bind_param()`. The code you added looks fine, except for the $parameters[] .= $student_id`, as mentioned previously, which should be `$parameters[] = $student_id;`  Use `[] =` to append to an array.

Comment: @user2048994 You have 2 of them above. `$parameters[] = $student_id;` and `$parameters[] = $_POST["student"];` Both of those should be `=`, not `.=` as you have them.

Comment: @user2048994 You have `$parameters[] .= $_POST['student']` way up in the `default` case in your top block of code.  That `.=` should be just `=`.

Comment: @user2048994 The `if()` version is clearer I would say.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you, I will give it a go, I will clear my previous comments to clean it up the page

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Just a slight issue I am receiving, first can you chrck if it is fine that at top of UPDATE code if it was ok to set ` $where[] = "q.SessionId = ?";` and the two lines below correctly for that where condition. But main question is the mysqli error I am receiving

Answer (score 1):

```
$p_student = -1;
if(isset($_POST["student"]) && filter_var($_POST["student"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== FALSE && trim($_POST["student"]) >= 0 ) {
    $p_student = $_POST["student"];
}

....
```

Comment: In the case of a positive ID, I would use `ctype_digit` instead of `is_numeric`. It would reject values such as `1e4`, `4.12`, ...

Comment: I think you meant is_int() or similar. Thanks. Updated code to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: My apologies, I think it's time for me to rest :) I meant `ctype_digit`, thanks for the notice.

Comment: Actually, is_int() is wrong as well. It does not work as expected with strings. Updated code to use filter_var instead. ctype_digit would probably work as well.

Comment: @kufudo Hi, I am getting an `unexpected T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL error` when I try your solution

Comment: @kufudo Look at update so you can see what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @user2048994 Think I had an extra closing right-bracket. Updated the code. Try it now.

Comment: @kufudo I am just attempting something, if that fails then I refer to your solution :)

Comment: @kufudo Can you include a seperate edit or an update if you have an idea on what you think needs to change in block of code in update. I am receiving an error but can you just have a general check on the code to see if the code looks ok or if you see any other problems?

Comment: What error are you getting now? I don't have access to a PHP environment at the moment.

Comment: @kufudo It is mentioned in a quote in the update `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ... on line 344 Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ... on line 354`

Comment: You're using the procedural style of mysqli_real_escape_string(), for which the first parameter should be the instance of your mysqli object. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @kufudo I tried this which did not seem to work `$student_id = (isset($_POST['student'])) ? $student_id->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['student'])) : null ;
` his gives me an undefined student_id variable

Comment: @kufudo if I change it to `$mysqli->real_escape_string` then I get undefined $mysqli variable

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to say, but it sounds like you're not initializing $mysqli, or not in the same scope anyhow. See the example here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @kufudo With the help of Jari we managed to get rid of the error but it does not display any output if one or both drop down menus has the `All` option selected. Please look at comment s with Jari for me info

Answer (score 0):

If you think that $_POST['student'] may be sometimes:

- 0 as int
- "" or "0" as string
- an empty array

Do not use `empty() ;`

Check this one `(Updated)`:

```
$student_id = (isset($_POST['student'])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['student'])) : null ;

if (is_numeric($student_id)){ //If student ID is a numeric value
  $where[] = "sa.StudentId = ?" ;
  $parameters[] = ((int)$student_id == -1) ? "sa.Student_id" : $student_id  ;
  $parameterTypes .= "i" ;
}
```

Comment: I have a drop down menu, which can you look at update above, what I am trying to do with the case statement is that if user selects `All` option `-1` then do not perform anything, else any other option then perform the default. With your if statement, what should I call the `All` option value?

Comment: I am recieving an error using your method but can you please look up date and state to me what I am doing incorrectly

Comment: This error `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ... on line 344 Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in ... on line 354`

Comment: `$student_id = (isset($_POST['student'])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['student'])) : null ;` Just use the updated code

Comment: This line causing problem: `$student_id = (isset($_POST['student'])) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['student'])) : null ;
` Is it like kufudo mentioned, it is written procedural style and not object orientated style? I tried the updated code but no change.

Comment: `$student_id = (isset($_POST['student'])) ? $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['student'])) : null ;` then try this one

Comment: It is giving me these errors: `Undefined variable: mysqli in ... on line 345 Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in ... on line 345`. I assume I need to use a `global $mysqli` variable but when I use this then no details are outputted. So I updated code in update so you can see what the current code looks like but I have taken away the `global $mysqli` as I might put it in wrong place.

Comment: `$student_id = (isset($_POST['student'])) ? (int) $_POST['student'] : null ;` If you struggle with mysqli, you could you this code.

Comment: No errors which is great but no details outputted if both drop down menus or one of the drop down menus has `All` option (`-1` value) selected, it only outputs details if both drop down menus are single student and single question